# PHP Variable - Multiply pages

Tags: php, variables

I have a functions.php page, I have included in ALL my other php pages. What I want is a function in my functions.php page, I can use in all the other pages.

I have tried this:

```
    function getSetting()
    {
        $r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");
        if(mysql_num_rows($r) == 0)
            return false;
        else
            $sdata=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);

        return $sdata;
    }
```

The thing I want to, I want to get the data from the row next to the name in the following picture: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0bci8x472

Example:

If I write $sdata['sitename'], I want it to output "ptcify"

Thanks!

Comment: Where actually is the question? You could simply put the function above inside your functions.php, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC as documented at this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

There are a lot of things you could do to further improve your code implementation i.e OOP, using better database abstraction libraries(even switching to PDO insted of PHP_MYSQL is an improvement), but this should work straight of the bat.

Answer (score 1):

Most questions usually have a `?` in them somewhere, to indicate an actual question. I'm not sure what the problem with your code is, but I'm guessing you're only getting a single "setting" result - if that query returns multiple rows, you have to loop over the result set and get each row, THEN return:

```
$r = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
$sdata = array()
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
   $sdata[] = $row;
}
return $sdata
```

---

edit

```
$sql = "SELECT setting_name, setting_value FROM settings"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$sdata = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sdata[$row['setting_name']] = $row['setting_value'];
}

return $sdata;
```

Comment: Edited answer to show how to do what you want. Next time, include such information in the original question.