# How can I send a variable across php pages

Tags: php, variables, session-variables

I would like to create a variable in one php page and then use it another php page, is there any way this can be done?

Comment: How are those two php pages connected to each other? With a link in the browser? Is it like so: [PHP Variable - Multiply pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998386/php-variable-multiply-pages) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put something in session variable, which can be accessed on any page

Answer (score 1):

Use session variables.

First of all every page you want to use sessions on needs to have the function session_start(); declared at the top of every page. You then can use the session superglobal to store things.

```
Page1.php:
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['variable_name'] = 'some string';
    ?>

Page2.php:
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['variable_name'];
    ?>
```

Page2.php will show: some string

You can store strings, ints, arrays etc. Good Luck.

Comment: @p.campbell thanks, i got confused there for a second because i was in the middle of doing what you did, you just beat me to it by 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, depending on your setup and your needs.

- One of the most common ways is to use [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variables.  This would store the value(s) server-side in a way that's accessible anywhere in the PHP application.  The value will eventually time out and be lost if not persisted elsewhere, though.
- You could store the value in a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).  This would mean that the browser will send the value each time it accesses a page, so there's a little more network overhead.  This will allow you to set the cookie to never expire so the value persists across multiple visits to the website.  However, cookies are also at the mercy of the users since they're stored client-side.  Some users may not allow you to set cookies, some may delete them afterward, etc.
- You could store the value in some kind of persistent server-side storage, such as a [database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) or even just a [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.file.php).  This would allow you to manage your data server-side and separate its persistence from the PHP application, since applications are more transient and not reliable for long-term data persistence.
- You can even just add the value to hyperlinks in one page to pass it along as URL parameters to other pages.  Something like: `<a href="otherpage.php?value=<?php echo urlencode($someValue) ?>">click here</a>`  This would allow you to pass the value along to the next page and then completely forget about it after it's been used, if you don't need to keep it around for anything else.

As with many things, you have many options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, read about [sessions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) or [cookies](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about linking two PHP pages, you can just add it to a link:

one.php:

```
<a href="two.php?variable=<?php echo rawurlencode($variable);>"link</a>
```

two.php:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['variable']); ?>
```

See [Variables From External Sources<sup>­Docs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) and [`$_GET`<sup>­Docs</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need a session variable.
Make it like this:

```
$_SESSION['my_var'] = 'your_value';
```

Then, you just need to use `$_SESSION['my_var']` everywhere you need it as a global variable.
Pay attention that you have to put `session_start();` in the first line of your file codes everywhere you want to work with PHP sessions.